# Whats wrong with this else if statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Basically my controller is just grabbing all members: @members = Member.all and Im looping through them while checking to see if they have a profile picture uploaded and if not then the default should be loaded:

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
    <% unless member.image.nil? %>
      <li style="float:left; width:100px;">
        <%= image_tag(member.image.url(:tiny)) %>
        <%= link_to member.email, member_path(member)  %>
      </li>
      <% else %>
      <li style="float:left; width:100px;">
        <%= image_tag("default_member_small.jpg") %>
        <%= link_to member.email, member_path(member)  %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It seems to think every member has a profile image, and the image tag is calling "images/tiny/missing.png" for the missing images.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are using paperclip, if you are, you should not use **nil?**, you should use **present?**:

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
    <% if member.image.present? %>
      <li style="float:left; width:100px;">
        <%= image_tag(member.image.url(:tiny)) %>
        <%= link_to member.email, member_path(member)  %>
      </li>
      <% else %>
      <li style="float:left; width:100px;">
        <%= image_tag("default_member_small.jpg") %>
        <%= link_to member.email, member_path(member)  %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And instead of having an if you should just have this image named as paperclip expects it, there should not have any ifs in your code for this kind of handling.

Comment: Whoops, that's true, fixed now.

Comment: whoops yea, I forgot to mention Im using paperclip. that did it, thanks!